# Can you change a hard drive’s VolumeID (and other device’s GUID) on an AzureVM?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

With a physical server, one can use a program like Sysinternal’s **Volume ID Changer** to change the VolumeID for the machine’s hard drives.

1. Would this work on an Azure VM?
2. Can you change or set the VolumeID using the Azure Portal or via Azure Powershell?
3. Similarly if you are using an Azure WebApp to host an ASP.Net application, can you change or set the Volume ID associated with this WebApp?

If Azure provides such functions, does this apply to other “physical” resources?

Answer (score 0):

Q1 - Yes, it can be work on Azure VM. See in [windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/change-drive-letter#change-the-drive-letters).

Q2 - Yes, you can use the custom script to change the VolumeID through PowerShell or in the portal.

Q3 - You cannot do the change in the host machine for Azure Web App. There are the limitations about it.

> Applications can read the system drive as controlled by ACLs on the
>   drive. Applications cannot write to any location on the system drive,
>   as implemented in the sandbox (i.e. even if ACLs allowed writing to a
>   location on system drive, the sandbox would restrict it).

For details, see [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

And some resources such as Azure VM, you can do the change in it because you have the full permission of it. So if you have permission, you can change it. If you don't, you can't change it.

Hope this will help you. If you need for help you can give me the message.

Comment: How do you change the VolumeID in PowerShell or in the Azure portal?